# Hidden folders and files are accessible if the drive is copied to another system?

Tags: laptop

I am worried that an unknown person accessed my laptop and the entire drive is copied. One folder with few confidential files was made as hidden (entire folder and files from **folder >view option**)
So will that folder and its files visible and accessible to him??

Answer (score 3):

It is trivial to discover hidden folders & files on Windows. It even exists as a user option.

[image]

The only way to protect your data in case a bad actor accesses your hardware directly is to have the drive encrypted.

Comment: You can either encrypt the File System (EFS) or encrypt the entire drive (BitLocker) outside one of those methods, an administrator on a system can take ownership of any folder that exists on a drive, including a drive from another Windows installation.  There are a few folders (Windows Apps) for instance that make it difficult to change the owner of the contents, without breaking features, but changing the ownership can still be done.  In other words, viewing hidden contents is a trivial task for an Administrator.